# Meteor on Windows 10 cmd

Tags: javascript, meteor, logging, cmd, server

I'm having some issues with meteor in the windows cmd. The server logs get all scrambled and  unreadable after a change on the server and rebuilding. Here's an image so you can see what I mean:

[image]

Has anyone run into this? Any solutions for it?

I tried using cmd.exe, cmder, powershell. They all have the same problem. This started happening after the 1.5 update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like settings legacy console fixes the problem